# Bizarre lock/unlock behavior on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running 4.0.4

Tags: android, tablet, galaxy-tab

Whenever the screen is locked, onPause -> onStop are called as per usual, however, when the device screen wakes up to unlock, onStart -> onResume is called *before* the device is unlocked.

There is no wake/screen-based listener or request for the feature in play.

This sort of behavior has only been experienced on this device so far, regardless of it being in portrait or landscape position (either upon unlock or during app execution).

However I do not have any other tablets or 4.0.4 devices available to see if it is a tablet issue, Android version issue, *this* tablet issue or any possible combination of the three.

Anyone else experienced this sort of behavior and/or can cast a light on what in the seven hells is going on here?

Comment: well display will require some time(in milliseconds) to show the pixels from the state when it was off. Think of it like a monitor when you power off and start again it takes time. I am not so sure if this is always the case though

Comment: But isn't it supposed to only call the onStart method when the device has been actually unlocked, as opposed to merely waken up?